# How do I set default pdf file name in crystal viewer while exporting it?

Tags: crystal-reports, viewer

I have devoloped an application in Visual Foxpro 9.0 using Crystal reports 10 as report designer. Database in SQL 2005. 
For report preivew, I have used Crystal Report Viewer 10. 
My problem is, while exporting it in PFD through Report viewer, How do I set default File name for the exported file? By default it gives name of rpt file as default name of PDF file.

Answer (score 4):

You can do it by setting the report tile which the default file name you wish to have.

```
cr.SummaryInfo.ReportTitle = "Default File name you want"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the ReportDocument.SummaryInfo.ReportTitle property prior to the export - I think this is used as the default name.

Answer (score 0):

This is dangerous, but you can try setting `CrystalReportViewer1.ID = "ExportName";`
where CrystalReportViewer1 is the control specified in your .aspx file(in my case atleast)

```
<CR:CrystalReportViewer ID="CrystalReportViewer1" runat="server" 
    AutoDataBind="True" EnableDatabaseLogonPrompt="false" 
    onunload="CrystalReportViewer1_Unload" />

<%@ Register assembly="CrystalDecisions.Web, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304" namespace="CrystalDecisions.Web" tagprefix="CR" %>
```

Hope this helps!

**UPDATE**

Rather than trying the above, call the ExportToHttpResponse method.
In my case, I have

```
cryRpt.ExportToHttpResponse(ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat, Response, true, "Friendly Document Name here");
```

The first parameter of ExportToHttpResponse() is selecting the type of export format you need, i.e. PDF. (*ExportFormatType*)

The second parameter is your UI Page Response unit that is sent to the client. You can just use Response here. (*HttpResponse*)

The third parameter is whether you need the report to be sent as an attachement to the client, which you do - so the boolean value here of is True. (*boolean*)

The forth parameter is a *string* which is the name you want the file to be named.

Hope this helps!